# Why this dispatch action is not working in the react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to dispatch in redux,
The action will handle `true or false` for a certain property.
What I am doing now is not drawing data from the api, I am just handling the app state,

My actions is something like this in the redux file

```
export const chooseShippingAddressFunc = (data) => {
    dispatch({
        type: CHOOSE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
        payload: data
    })
}
```

The reducer is

```
export const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHOOSE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:
      return {...state, chooseShippingAddress: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Initial State is something Like this.

```
const initialState = {
  chooseShippingAddress: false,
};
```

What I want to do is if I press a button from the component
The `false initial value will change to true`

So inside the component
I am writing something like this, Take note that there are many other redux functions I am just
not shown in the reducer since its not related to my problem

```
const shipAll = (shippingId) => {
    setShippingAll(true);
    setShippingCountry(false);
    setLoading(true);

    let dataToSend = {
      OrderId: cartList.OrderDTO.Id,
      ShippingMethodID: shippingId,
    };
    dispatch(postShippingMethod(tokenData, dataToSend))
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(fetchCart(tokenData));
       dispatch(chooseShippingAddressFunc(true))

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert('Failed to set shipping method. Please try again Later');
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

The problem is that when ever I tried to dispatch the action. I always went into the catch block.

If I remove this line from the code

```
dispatch(chooseShippingAddressFunc(true))
```

The app is working fine. So What is the problem here?

Comment: can you console the error and post that too

Answer (score 1):

Since your action creator is

```js
export const chooseShippingAddressFunc = (data) => {
    dispatch({
        type: CHOOSE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
        payload: data
    })
}
```

and you are calling

```js
dispatch(chooseShippingAddressFunc(true))
```

you are essentially calling

```
dispatch(dispatch({
        type: CHOOSE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
        payload: true
}))
```

but you only should `dispatch` once.

Write your action creator as

```js
export const chooseShippingAddressFunc = (data) => ({
    type: CHOOSE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
    payload: data
})
```

instead.
If this is a thunk that should dispach multiple actions internally, you would need to write it like this:

```js
export const chooseShippingAddressFunc = (data) => (dispatch) => {
    // more logic here
    dispatch({
        type: CHOOSE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
        payload: data
    })
    // more logic here
}
```

Generally: you are writing a very old style of redux here that we do not recommend learning or using in new applications any more. You are probably following an outdated tutorial. Please follow the official tutorials at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts to learn modern redux, which is very different and requires a lot less code.